# starting voice search when screen is locked

Tags: android

**My goal**: I want to be able to start Google Maps Navigation when I'm in the car without having to reach for my phone.

**My idea**: I am writing an app that can be started via Bluetooth by my car using a smart device link. The important point is that I can launch an activity. My plan is that the activity starts a voice search via intent and uses the result for a query to maps navigation.

**My problem**: This works as long as the screen is already unlocked. But when locked it doesn't start the voice search and `onActivityResult` is called right away with `resultCode` is 0. As you can see below, I tried turning on the screen, but that didn't help.

**My question**: Any ideas on how to wake the screen correctly or how to make the voice search work nevertheless?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON );
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                String text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS).get(0);
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(String.format("google.navigation:q=%s", text));
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                mapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried WakefulBroadcastReceiver:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: i just tried it, but there is noch startActivityForResult in IntentService, so i can't start the voice search there and if i try to make the Service call startActivityForResult from the Activity above(which is visible then) i get the same result as before